# Excel/VBA Automation Errors due to Office Service Pack 3.0 caused by Forms

Tags: windows, excel, vba, ms-office, windows-update

After installing all latest windows updates my Excel VBA code is showing an automation error at the very start of the first module. It contains some forms as well as numerous modules of VBA code. However, when removing the forms (and associated code) everything is fine.

The same thing happened about a year ago after some other windows updates. Back then deleting the .exd files did the trick, but the current updates (including Service Pack 3) seem to be different.

What is going on and how can I get the forms to work? All the code is unchanged and has survived all previous windows/office updates. Running Windows 7 (same happening on Vista machine) and Office 2007.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I used to see this a lot with [Visual Basic and Crystal Reports](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22automation%20error%22%20%22crystal%20report%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&source=hp&channel=np); either due to a bad deployment or [DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell).

So, my guess is that it's not the code but perhaps some 3rd party controls (OCXs, DLLs) you're using.

Check your References (In VBA IDE, click Tools and References) and to see where each DLL is pointing.

See if any of the dates on the libraries are different than a working machine and you may find the culprit.

---

**Edit**

The OP found the problem by following the steps above.

The fix for this particular issue is to unregister mscomctl.ocx:

```
regsvr32 /u mscomctl.ocx
```

Then register it:

```
regsvr32 mscomctl.ocx
```

Comment: Not straight forward to compare, but only key difference I found is "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6) MSCOMCTL.OCX which is dated 6/6/12 on the updated (and not working) machine and 4/11/11 on an "old" one. Not using any 3rd party controls and all worked fine until windows updates ran.

Comment: @Rob I would think comparing dates to files would be pretty straight forward, but what evs.  The [Mscomctl.ocx](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597986) was in a security update from yesterday (August 14th) and you say you just installed the latest updates on the computer.  It may be the issue, it may not, but since this is something that changed in the past 24 hours, you might want to try uninstalling the specific update or unregistering the new ocx and then registering the "working control".  Would take maybe five minutes to see if that's your issue.

Comment: Comparing dates was awkward since machines not identical and some data stamps seem to be depend on when exactly updates were ran previously. As you say unregistering and registering works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Same issue here, problem completely solved after registering mscomctl.ocx!

for Windows 7 or 2008 - remember to run cmd.exe "as administrator", and then:

for 32bit Windows systems:
regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\mscomctl.ocx

for 64bit Windows systems:
regsvr32 c:\windows\syswow64\mscomctl.ocx

Answer (score 2):

Same issue with VBA for AutoCAD.  In my case, registering the new mscomctl.ocx with regsvr32 was enough to fix the issue.

Comment: Indeed, all you need is "regsvr32 /u mscomctl.ocx" and "regsvr32 mscomctl.ocx" ran as admin.

Answer (score 2):

We couldn´t solve the problem by re-registering mscomctl.ocx. 
But we solved it by removing a "progress bar object form" wich calls mscomctl.ocx... We replaced it with application.statusbar.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687441 for an update that may fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem. In our Add-In, we were able to trace the problem to a declaration of a variable as Excel.Application. The reference to this object is in the Excel.exe file, so it is very unclear as to which files got messed up.

The machines that have this problem were all updated early this morning (15 Aug 2012) with the following updates (sorry for not posting links, as a new user, I'm limited to only two per post):

[Security Update for Microsoft Office 2007 suites (KB2596615)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2596615)

[Security Update for Microsoft Office 2007 suites (KB2596754)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2596754)

Security Update for Microsoft Office 2007 suites (KB2596856)

Security Update for Microsoft Office 2007 suites (KB2687441)

Update for Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 Junk Email Filter (KB2687400)

Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - August 2012 (KB890830)

At present, we have not found any information on the MSDN site that could clear this up. We're still trying to isolate this down further.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I got an unspecified error opening excel with my Add-In loading.
In the past, deleting the *.exd files in C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Application Data\Microsoft\Forms\ 
did the trick, but not this time.
When I attempted to open up the forms in my addin, I got a different error and I could not open the forms.
I ended up rolling back to last night prior to the update and everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here today after performing the update for Office 2007 Excel. Oddly, one system had no issues despite the update - the newest system. So after some inspection, I noticed this trouble-free system had different version of MSCOMCTL.OCX in windows\sysWOW64 then others. Here are the details of this activeX
Size: 1,070,152 bytes
created: 6/3/2012
modified: 6/6/2012
product version: 6.01.9834
So I copied this to the trouble one and it did the trick.

Also, you might want to check if these application extensions are present in windows\sysWOW64 or windows\system32 for 32-bit system
FM20.DLL (Modified Date: 7/7/2011, version 12.0.6604.1000, 1.13MB)
FM20ENU.DLL (Modified Date: 10/24/2008, version 12.0.6413.1000, 32.3KB)
Not sure where you can download these. I cannibalized them from other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on all of our terminal servers after one of the updates last night. Registering mscomctl.ocx fixed the problem for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Un- and registering the MSCOMCTL.ocx did the trick for me:

> 1. Open an administrative-level command prompt. Click START, and type RUN in the run command line. On Windows Vista and Windows 7 you will
>      see CMD.EXE appear in the quick search list. Right click CMD.EXE and
>      left click Run As Administrator. A black command prompt opens.
> 2. If on a 64-bit machine, type the following:   regsvr32.exe /u  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX
>
> Hit ENTER   then type   regsvr32.exe  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX
>   If on a 32-bit machine, type the following:   regsvr32.exe /u
>   C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX   hit ENTER   then type
>   regsvr32.exe C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX   Your Office program
>   should work again after doing this.

Please see also: http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2012/08/15/quot-unspecified-automation-error-quot-after-applying-ms12-060.aspx

Answer (score 0):

son of a gun...I re-registered C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX and everything works again.  Thanks so much to all that pointed that out.